# Error 404 RESTFul Service with Ajax

Tags: ajax, rest

I got a RESTful service call with ajax :

```
var request =   $.ajax({type: "GET",
        type : "GET",
        url : "/services/equipment/searchEquipments?pId="+id,
        cache : false
});
```

The java method in the service is declared as :

```
@GET
@Path("/searchEquipments/{pId}")
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public List<EquipmentVO> searchEquipments(@PathParam("pId") String pId){
```

I got a 404 return code.

I can't understand because after the call, the 404 code is on a weird URL :

```
http://localhost:7001/services/equipement/searchEquipments?pId=00192772&_=1408446932784
```

I can't figure why there's `&_=1408446932784` at the end ??? It's not a part of the made URL during the call.

Any idea ?

Comment: `&_=1408446932784` comes from `$.ajax` library to avoid cached result and tell the browser to make fresh request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESTfull service does not accept argument in this way.
the argumant should be a part of the path (as it is defined)

so you should send a get request to "/services/equipment/searchEquipment/"+id
(without the ?pId=)

for example, if the Pid is 123, the path should be
/services/equipment/searchEquipment/123

Comment: RESTFull accepts parameters in POST method but not using GET. Also the pattern specifies the id as part of the URL and as a parameter